# can I use ListFragment with Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-listfragment, navigation-drawer

I am working on an android app and I want to make a ListFragment and use it in navigation drawer as a fragment. It is possible?

I make the ListFragment but i have errors on my main activity:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    ListFragment lf=null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        lf = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    if (lf != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, lf).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```

**The error is: the method replace(int,Fragment) in the type FragmentFransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int,ListFragment).**

This error is at this line of code(at replace):

```
if (lf != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, lf).commit();
```

where lf is a ListFragment.

**So can I use ListFragment with Navigation Drawer?**

Comment: Can you post the imports for ListFragment?

Comment: for the ListFragment i import: android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

Comment: You need to use `import android.app.ListFragment` coz probably you extend Activity and you are using `getFragmentManager()`. I could have answered assuming but i was waiting for you reply which came now

Comment: I extend FragmentActivity. I think the problem is that in the navigation drawer I want to use a ListFragment and a Fragment too...

Comment: if i use getSupportFragmentManager() for the ListFragment it works but for the fragment doesn't....

Comment: Fragment as nothing to do with this. ListFragment will work jsut fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ListFragment` from `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`. If you indeed want to use support package, your `Activity` should extend `FragmentActivity` and then you should call `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. Otherwise please use `android.app.ListFragment`. So, probaly you should replace this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

with this:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
```

Comment: I solve it with getSupportFragmentManager() and the android.support.v4.app.ListFragment import .But another error appeard.In the navigation drawer I want to use a listFragment and a Fragment. Now the error it is at the fragment:'code' if (fragment != null) {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();